# Elasticsearch on object nested under objects array

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have the following index structure:

```
{
  "title": "Early snow this year",
  "body": "After a year with hardly any snow, this is going to be a serious winter",
  "source": [
    {
      "name":"CNN",
      "details": {
        "site": "cnn.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"BBC",
      "details": {
        "site": "bbc.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have a bool query to try and retrieve this document here:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "snow",
          "fields" : ["title", "body"] 
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
                { "term" : {"source.name" : "bbc"}},
                { "term" : {"source.details.site" : "BBC.COM"}}
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But it is not working with zero hits, how should I modify my query? It is only working if I remove the `{ "term" : {"source.details.site" : "BBC.COM"}}`.

Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "news" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "article" : {
        "properties" : {
          "body" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source" : {
            "properties" : {
              "details" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "site" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your mappings too?

Comment: use `match` instead of `term`

Comment: Yeah sure in a sec, I am using default mappings BTW

Comment: @Val I tried using match but the behavior is not what I want. For instance, if I changed to match and if I change my query from BBC.com to BBB.com it will still return hits. I only want exact match on my filter query

Comment: @steve that is because it is being tokenized at index time and bbc will be a token in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a term query on "source.details.site". Term query means that the value you provide will not be analysed at query time. If you are using default mapping then source.details.site will be lowercased. Now when you query it with term and "BBC.COM", "BBC.COM" will not be analysed and ES is trying to match "BBC.COM" with "bbc.com" (because it was lowercased at index time) and result is false.
You can use match instead of term to get it analysed. But its better to use term query on your keyword field, it you know in advance the exact thing that would have been indexed. Term queries have good advantage of caching from ES side and it is faster than match queries.

You should clean your data at index time as you will write once and read always. So anything like "/", "http" should be removed if you are not losing the semantics. You can achieve this from your code while indexing or you can create custom [analysers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) in your mapping. But do remember that custom analysers won't work on keyword field. So, if you try to achieve this on ES side, you wont be able to do aggregations on that field without enabling field data, that should be avoided. We have an experimental support for normalisers in latest update, but as it is experimental, don't use it in production. So in my opinion you should clean the data in your code.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! One more question tho, I noticed if my source.details.site contains value such as "http://bbc.com" and if I query using "http://bbc.com" (both lowercase) there are no hit. My best guess is the forward slash is causing issue, how should I escape them properly?

Comment: @steve Are you indexing like "bbc.com/" ?

Comment: Huh somehow my http and 2 forward slashes are removed by StackOverflow. I meant if my source.details.site contains "http: //bbc.com" without the space

Comment: I understand your updated answer but may I ask why should I remove things like "/" and "http"? Should I remove any special character too, as in what is the scope of the data cleaning?

Comment: @steve Cleaning part depends on the type of data and operations that you have. You can remove special characters as long as you don't lose semantics. Only thing to keep in mind is that in case of term query, you should exactly know what you are looking for. So if you will be always knowing the exact value while querying then you can skip cleaning part. I update my index by scrapping the web and I am not sure about the data I will be getting. If i just care about the domain and not query params then I will clean it because then I can term filter docs with "bbc.com" only  after cleaning it.

Comment: Imagine if there are urls-  abc.com?q=bbc.com, abc.com?q=xyz.com. I just want to aggregate by domain. In case I do it without cleaning, both will fall in different buckets. But if I clean it before indexing I can achieve what I want. So it depends on your use case.

Comment: Let's use URL as an example and say I want to skip the cleaning and storing the entire URL and possible query params into ES, say "http: //bbc.com/?cat=finance" and later if I wanted to query and retrieve this particular news article, how should I do it as even though my search query have exactly the same "http: //bbc.com/?cat=finance" there are no hits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142880/discussion-between-krrish-and-steve).